# How to upload a file to mediafire with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rest-client, mediafire

I'm searching along months (maybe 1 year) a way to upload a file to mediafire.

I know mediafire use flash, I know mediafire API is so private...

But I know too a program called "File&Image uploader" that can upload files to mediafire (HOW?!)

my knowledge about networks are very, VERY basics, but i could make a Ruby script to upload images to Imageshack using the API and the "rest_client" gem, so maybe... i can do the same for mediafire... (With help)

I tried all... ALL!:
curl, wget, wput, ssl, ruby example scripts, python example scripts, perl example scripts, and a lot of unuseful CLI apps for linux and windows that I don't remember the name now...

After all, at the moment i don't know the method to upload a file to mediafire.

Well, at this point, My questions are:

1. Is it possible to upload a file (no matter if in my account or in "free" mode) to mediafire, using ruby or python? And anyone could give me a brief example or tell me the easiest way?
2. If not possible to mediafire, could you tell me a FREE and GOOD server (I mean without re-captcha) with ability to upload a file using the rest_client gem ? (or another easy way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm sure this answer won't be optimal to what the writer desires, but here goes anyhow.

If you want to upload files with media content you should really be taking a look at Amazon's S3 API.

http://aws.amazon.com/s3/

Yes, you may have to pay at a certain point, but the free point on S3 will equal or exceed the free point on mediafire.

The difference is, that on every level S3 is a better delivery method for your media files, and if you're attempting to abuse free offers you will have an equally frustrating time everywhere

Comment: Hello, I appreciate your help, but my intention is not for private use (or have to pay for it).

Sorry but that can not solve my problem